# Axios Flask. Parsing fileblob and json

Tags: python-3.x, vue.js, python-requests, axios, form-data

We need to send `json with userId` and `file` to the server simultaneosuly.
For client side *Axios* library is used.

```
 const userId = this.$store.getters['login/userId'];
                const obj = {
                    userId: userId
                };
                const json = JSON.stringify(obj);
                const blob = new Blob([json], {
                    type: 'application/json'
                });
                const fd = new FormData();
                const vue = this;
                async function submitAllFiles(){
                    let file = vue.files[0];
                        fd.append('file', file);
                        fd.append(userId, blob);
                        const options = {
                            onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
                                ...
                            }
                        };

                        await vue.axios
                            .post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload_to_db', fd, options)
                            .then((response) => {
                                console.log(response);
                            })
```

Here is server part of processing

```
@api.route('/upload_to_db', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def upload_to_db():
    print('Trying to upload file')
    print(request.files)

    teacher_id = request.files.getlist('userId')

    # teacher_id = json.load(request.files['userId'])

    # print(teacher_id.get('blob'))

    files = request.files.getlist('file')
    print(files)
    if insert_pdf_into_table(teacher_id,
                             files[0]):
        return jsonify({'result': True})
    # print('Sending request to /simple_check')
    return jsonify({'result': False})
```

Since we can easily parse file-part with standard files[0].filename and files[0].read()
But how we can parse json-part ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use Blob. Just append to formData object.

Client side:

```
const userId = this.$store.getters['login/userId'];
                const fd = new FormData();
                const vue = this;
                async function submitAllFiles(){
                    let file = vue.files[0];
                        fd.append('file', file);
                        fd.append(userId, userId);
                        const options = {
                            onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
                                ...
                            }
                        };

                        await vue.axios
                            .post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload_to_db', fd, options)
                            .then((response) => {
                                console.log(response);
                            })
```

Server side:

```
@api.route('/upload_to_db', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def upload_to_db():
    user_id = request.form.get('userId')
    files = request.files.getlist('file')

    if insert_pdf_into_table(
            user_id=user_id,
            filename=files[0]):
        return jsonify({'result': True})
    return jsonify({'result': False})
```